# create local notification in xamarin ios with http request

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

i have xamarin forms app that support notification, i have done it in android with broadcast receiver now i have to do notification in ios ! , my service is depending on API REST so i want every 60 second ios app run HTTP request and get data then show it as notification, i searched for many days but i can't reach to my approach ?
if this is impossible can i use nuget or something like that in ios project only "in xamarin forms solution " or not ?

```
        content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
        content.Title = "Notification Title";
        content.Subtitle = "Notification Subtitle";
        content.Body = "This is the message body of the notification.";
        content.Badge = 1;
        content.CategoryIdentifier = "message";

        var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(60, true);


        var requestID = "sampleRequest";
        var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
        {
            if (err != null)
            {
                // Do something with error...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for generating a local notification on iOS

```
var alertsAllowed = false;
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettings((settings) =>
{
    alertsAllowed = (settings.AlertSetting == UNNotificationSetting.Enabled);
});

if (alertsAllowed)
{
    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
    content.Title = "Incident Recorder";
    content.Subtitle = "Not Synchronised";
    content.Body = "There are one or more new incidents that have not been synchronised to the server.";

    var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(5, false);

    var requestID = "sampleRequest";
    var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
    {
        if (err != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.LocalizedFailureReason);
        }
    });
}
```

The first parameter in CreateTrigger is how long before the notification is generated. I notice you have 60 in yours. Also bear in mind a notification will not appear if your app is foregrounded.

Comment: so where i can call my http request to import data from server automatically after 60 like me or 5 like you ?

Comment: The 60 (or 5) is nothing to do with how often you import data from the server. It is how long to delay showing the notification. You should call the server from your shared (PCL) code possibly using a timer. Once you have data call the platform specific code to trigger a notification.

Comment: in android platform there is a service that run the code in background without timer, i wonder if  is there's some thing like that in ios, anyway i think that i can't explain second question or i miss logic in ti :), thanks mr steve